# Gazebo 1.9 with ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-groovy, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all!

If I want to install Gazebo 1.9 on my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and ROS Groovy, do I need to uninstall the ROS-included Gazebo? If yes, how?

Thank you all!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67008/gazebo-1.9-with-ros-groovy-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts/) by [TabStock](https://answers.ros.org/users/5367/tabstock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-07-11**:
Could you go a bit more into detail how and what you've done? I'm pretty much in the same situation (aside from Kubunto 13.04)...

**Comment by [Rasmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/6846/rasmus/) on 2013-09-20**:
I have a short guide on how I did it, but for some reason I cant post answers (containing links..)
Sorry

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-09-20**:
I've decided to go with V-REP by Coppelia Robotics instead of Gazebo. Works as well and is, in my opinion, much more comfortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out!!! Just dig around on the Gazebo Tutorials a bunch. There are some sections that actually give the command.

---

Originally posted by [TabStock](https://answers.ros.org/users/5367/tabstock/) with karma: 61 on 2013-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0